# How to bind a command inside a View to a ViewModel in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have this android View, where I'm using LegacyBar:

```
public class BaseView : MvxActivity
{
    public override void SetContentView(int layoutResId)
    {
        base.SetContentView(layoutResId);
        var bar = FindViewById<LB.LegacyBar>(Resource.Id.actionbar);
        bar.SetHomeLogo(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        var attr = this.GetType()
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActivityAttribute), true)
            .FirstOrDefault() as ActivityAttribute;
        if (attr != null)
            bar.Title = attr.Label;
        bar.SetHomeAction(new ActionLegacyBarAction(ApplicationContext, doHomeAction, Resource.Drawable.Icon));
    }

    public ICommand homeActionClicked { get; set; }
    private void doHomeAction()
    {
        if (homeActionClicked != null && homeActionClicked.CanExecute(null))
            homeActionClicked.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

What is the right way to bind `homeActionClicked` defined inside this View to a Command in its ViewModel?
Or maybe I should make a custom control and put the bar inside it and then bind the control's command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this property, you can do as @Chris suggests - using `base.ViewModel` and casting to give you access to the ViewModel, or you can use FluentBinding if you want to do binding inside `OnCreate` - e.g.

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<BaseView, BaseViewModel>();
set.Bind(this).For(v => v.homeActionClicked).To(vm => vm.GoHomeCommand);
set.Apply();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reference your ViewModel as a property in your view so you can access it's property's and set a command from your view to the viewmodel.

```
protected MvvMCore.Core.ViewModels.NavigationBarViewModel NavigationBarViewModel {
            get{ return base.ViewModel as MvvMCore.Core.ViewModels.NavigationBarViewModel; }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a code snippet from one of my projects. This is the namespace of my MvvMCross project ( the core ) , that links with the Android project. If you place this code somewhere in your activity, you will be able to acces your viewmodel in your view. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you. It's more or less what I thought I'd do. I think for the purpose of my app, I'll go with the Fluent approach, though.